# How to prove the convergence of a sequence satisfying $a_{k+1} \leq c_{1} a_{k} + \frac{c_{2}}{a_{k}} +1$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Assume a positive sequence $\left\{ a_{k} \right\}$ satisfying
 \begin{equation}
  a_{k+1} \leq c_{1} a_{k} + \frac{c_{2}}{a_{k}} +1, k \in \mathbb{N}
\end{equation}
where $c_{1},c_{2},a_{1} > 0$. If $0 < c_{1} <1$, then

1. the sequence $\left\{ a_{k} \right\}$ converges.
2. the sequence $\left\{ a_{k} \right\}$ is bounded.

Which is right? How to prove it?!

Comment: @DanielFischer There's a second quesiton :P

Comment: @BCLC Yes, **now**.

Comment: Neither need hold, the sequence can be unbounded.

Comment: Yes. But its behavior is very strange.